Unable to Use Claude 3.5 Sonet Model on Vertex AI - Error 400: Project Not Allowed
I’m trying to call the Claude 3.5 Sonet model via Vertex AI in Python, but I’m encountering the following error:
anthropic.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Project `project_id` is not allowed to use Publisher Model `projects/project-name/locations/us-east5/publishers/anthropic/models/claude-3-5-sonnet@20240620`', 'status': 'FAILED_PRECONDITION'}}

Google Developer Console:

I’ve setup my account and I'm logged in
I’ve attached a valid billing account and my credit card information is up-to-date.

APIs Enabled:

I’ve enabled the Vertex AI API.
I’ve activated the Claude 3.5 Sonet model in the Vertex AI Model Registry.

Other Models Work Fine:
I’m able to successfully call models like Gemini without any issues.
Here’s the code I’m using to call the model:
client = AnthropicVertex(project_id=project_id, region="us-east5")

completion = client.messages.create(
    model="claude-3-5-sonnet@20240620",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    max_tokens=max_output_tokens,
    temperature=temperature,
)

Despite all these steps, I’m still getting the above error specifically for the Claude 3.5 Sonet model.
Questions:
Is there an additional step required to use Claude 3.5 Sonet on Vertex AI?
Are there specific permissions or configurations needed for this model?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much!!

Deleting the project in the Google Cloud and creating a new one helped

Technically, all the details to start your Claude 3.5 Sonnet Model on Vertex AI are given in these documentation.
If you're unable to resolve the issue, contact Google Cloud Support for further assistance in project permissions, project quotas, model availability in your region, and model quotas.
